# Java network server/client, cant find where is the failure

Tags: java

Hello I've reduced the code to this simple one:

Code from Server

```
byte[] data=new byte[1024];
try {
  providerSocket=new ServerSocket(port);
  while(true) {
    connection=providerSocket.accept();
    in=connection.getInputStream();
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    while((len=in.available())>0) {
      in.read(data,0,len);
      sb.append(new String(data,0,len));
      reset(data); //writes -1 value to all bytes...
      len=0;
    }
    System.out.println("Get "+sb.toString());
    //does the same if I close() in, connection or do not close anything
  }
}
catch(IOException ioException){ }
```

The client does somethig like:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
String s="Sample text";
out.write(s.getBytes());
out.flush();
out.close();
socket.close();
//closes cliente program
```

When I run Server and then I run client output is "Get Sample text", if I run again client output is "Get " whitout anything more, sure the error is very simple but I've tried everything I'm not viewing where it fails!!!

Why am I receiving ok the first transmission but not the next transmissions sent?
Sure my sample code has failures like not closing inputstream etc, but it does not change result if after the System.out.println() I write in.close() and/or connection.close()

Regards.

Comment: Put an `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block **always**.

Comment: Removed from code copied to be shorter, but there is a printStackTrace and System.err outputs, nothing fails in the try catch block...

Comment: If you're not showing the actual code, how are we supposed to see the actual problem?

Comment: This code has the problem, I've omited the variable declaration parts, comments in the code and e.printStacktrace() only in the code, it works the first time and no next time client calls the server, problem is not in omited variable declarations like InputStream in; not present in the sample, and there is not error message or exception thrown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `in.available()`, the method doesn't do what you think it does. Instead, move the `read()` call to the while-loop condition.

```
int bytesRead = 0;
while((bytesRead = in.read(data)) != -1)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Solved!!! Regards, I wanted to vote you a positive, but I'v not enough Karma. Thanks, if some day I have more karma and remember to search for the post I'll vote you, thanks!!!

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can't mark my answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

just comment out

```
  \\ out.flush();
 \\  out.close();
```

for a while and check,becuase i was also getting this error previously ,however this is the correct way but sometimes it creates problems.

Comment: Thanks but nothing changed, sometimes I get another message ok, but usually only first time I start the server and after that, nothing more is received (i did not search into client because i run client app, it finish and then i try again so is a "new" application, only server remains always running, of course...